# Access Denied on Samba shared files

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, users

I have set up samba server following this page https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Samba_Server/

What I did:

```
1. sudo apt-get install samba-common samba
2. sudo  adduser --no-create-home <username> 
3. sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
4. mkdir /mnt/FILESERVER
```

my /etc/samba/smb.conf looks like

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
netbios name = HoloFileServer
wins support = yes
dns proxy = no
name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast

interfaces = enp3s0
bind interfaces only = yes

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0

panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

server role = standalone server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user

usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

## my Shared
[Shared]
writeable = yes
path = /mnt/RAID/FILESERVER/
comment = Fileserver
guest account = <username>
wide links = no
security = user
```

Trying to access \fileServer\Share from Windows says Access Denied

Is something missing?

(I also already tried `chwon <username>:<usergroup> /mnt/FILESERVER`)

**EDIT:** 
- Applied change to adduser options as suggested
- Changed smb.conf

Answer (score 0):

By adding your user with the `--disabled-login` switch the result is as excerpted from the add user man page.

```
 --disabled-login
              Do  not  run passwd to set the password.  The user won't be able
              to use her account until the password is set.
```

I don't believe `smbpasswd -a` is working as you think as this excerpt from the smbpasswd man page indicates.

```
 Note that the
           default passdb backends require the user to already exist in the
           system password file (usually /etc/passwd), else the request to add
           the user will fail.
```

I believe that you can resolve the majority of the issues you've created for yourself by creating a password for the account in question with `sudo passwd <username>`

Another issue that I believe may be relevant to your difficulties is the usage of `--shell /bin/false` which as I understand it will [simply drop connection without explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false)

Sources:

`man adduser`

`man smbpasswd`

`man passwd`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's strange because in the set up I followed they recommend the `sudo  adduser --no-create-home --disabled-login --shell /bin/false <username>` especially for sharing files using the same login data on multible PCs. I will try now to reinstall samba adding the user just as a normal user without the "--" options

Comment: Ok I now tried it again with just `sudo adduser --no-create-home <uName>`, enetered the Unix password. Then did `sudo smbdpasswd -a <uName>`.
The is something strange because before adding this User I actually can see the folder "Share" if I open \\fileServer in a file-browser. After adding the user I can't login (access denied) and the system says that \\fileServer does not exist... (I use a copied smb.conf that is perfectly working on another Server .. ofcourse applying the needed changes as the path and interface and so on)

Comment: Using guest ok (allowing just anyone to connect) works perfect so it has to do something with this user authentication

Comment: Sorry for typing so much .. I've a strange situation again. Even though guest ok is enabled so anyone should be able to connect, it works after `sudo smbpasswd -x <username>` - so with no user configured for Samba. But after `sudo smbpasswd -a <username>` the access is denied though samba souldn't even ask for a password ..

Comment: -e
           This option specifies that the username following should be enabled
           in the local smbpasswd file, if the account was previously
           disabled. If the account was not disabled this option has no
           effect. Once the account is enabled then the user will be able to
           authenticate via SMB once again.

Comment: Hi I know the -e, -d, -a and -x options. The problem is as soon as I enable the user, no one can acces the Samba-folder not even if "guest ok = yes". As soon as I disable or delete the user it works fine (but of course we want authentication) so I really don't get where the mistake could be

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -l libpam-winbind` ? You might also find [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileprint-security.html) useful.